# High-Order Function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In the course of funcional programming with Scala, I saw two form of declaration of a `def`. But I don't know the diferences between them, and the name given for this. How I can get more information about this?

Declaration 1

`def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???`

Declaration 2

`def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is called the curried syntax.

You can apply the function partially, then results in returning of a new function.

```
scala> def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = f(a) + f(b)
sum: (f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> sum({x: Int => x + 1}) _
res10: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1115/108209958@474821de
```

Second one is uncurried syntax but still we can apply the function partially even in this case.

```
scala> def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = f(a) + f(b)
sum: (f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> sum({x: Int => x + 1}, _: Int, _: Int)
res11: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1116/1038002783@1a500561
```

Again new function returned when applied partially.

> There is no difference between above two declaration, Its just the syntactic sugar.